# Gradle build daemon disappeared unexpectedly (it may have been killed or may have crashed) while building Android project on Jenkins

Tags: android, jenkins, gradle

I have an Android Project that builds successfully on Android Studio.

Now I want to build it on Jenkins. But when I'm doing I got the following error:
Gradle build daemon disappeared unexpectedly (it may have been killed or may have crashed)

Exception is:

```
org.gradle.launcher.daemon.client.DaemonDisappearedException: Gradle build daemon disappeared unexpectedly (it may have been killed or may have crashed)
    at org.gradle.launcher.daemon.client.DaemonClient.handleDaemonDisappearance(DaemonClient.java:222)
    at org.gradle.launcher.daemon.client.DaemonClient.monitorBuild(DaemonClient.java:198)
    at org.gradle.launcher.daemon.client.DaemonClient.executeBuild(DaemonClient.java:162)
    at org.gradle.launcher.daemon.client.DaemonClient.execute(DaemonClient.java:125)
    at org.gradle.launcher.daemon.client.DaemonClient.execute(DaemonClient.java:80)
    at org.gradle.launcher.cli.RunBuildAction.run(RunBuildAction.java:43)
    at org.gradle.internal.Actions$RunnableActionAdapter.execute(Actions.java:173)
    at org.gradle.launcher.cli.CommandLineActionFactory$ParseAndBuildAction.execute(CommandLineActionFactory.java:241)
    at org.gradle.launcher.cli.CommandLineActionFactory$ParseAndBuildAction.execute(CommandLineActionFactory.java:214)
    at org.gradle.launcher.cli.JavaRuntimeValidationAction.execute(JavaRuntimeValidationAction.java:35)
    at org.gradle.launcher.cli.JavaRuntimeValidationAction.execute(JavaRuntimeValidationAction.java:24)
    at org.gradle.launcher.cli.CommandLineActionFactory$WithLogging.execute(CommandLineActionFactory.java:207)
    at org.gradle.launcher.cli.CommandLineActionFactory$WithLogging.execute(CommandLineActionFactory.java:169)
    at org.gradle.launcher.cli.ExceptionReportingAction.execute(ExceptionReportingAction.java:33)
    at org.gradle.launcher.cli.ExceptionReportingAction.execute(ExceptionReportingAction.java:22)
    at org.gradle.launcher.Main.doAction(Main.java:33)
    at org.gradle.launcher.bootstrap.EntryPoint.run(EntryPoint.java:45)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:498)
    at org.gradle.launcher.bootstrap.ProcessBootstrap.runNoExit(ProcessBootstrap.java:55)
    at org.gradle.launcher.bootstrap.ProcessBootstrap.run(ProcessBootstrap.java:36)
    at org.gradle.launcher.GradleMain.main(GradleMain.java:23)
```

I read related topics, but it does not help. I tried to build it using gradle daemon, and without it, but the problem still exists.

Comment: i already answer it go to this link
[this is from another post](https://stackoverflow.com/a/44693275/5832732)

Comment: Oh, thanks! I'll check it and let you know.

Comment: I tried removing lock files under `.gradle` directory at both home and project directories, then I tried additionally removing the `~/.gradle/caches`, quitting as many processes as possible to make room and setting the `-Xmx` for the daemon to `4GB`, making sure no other Java process exists, but none of these helped. I even tried blowing away both the `.gradle` directories in both home and project directories. It is hard to believe but it started working again after restarting the OS.

Comment: Regarding my above comment, I had been building with gradle in this project for over 2 years and this is the first time this happened, so maybe it is something to do with Mac than gradle. For reference, I was using macOS `10.15.7` and `adoptopenjdk-14.jdk` installed using Brew.

Comment: It is a combination of number of parellel demons are running and how much heapspace you are utlising.
- so check how much jeap is avaliable and create a configuration accordingly
#-Xms256m -Xmx1024m
- Number of forks = number of parallel test cases are exectuing
```
tasks.test {
maxParallelForks=2
}
```
so ideally you can expect minimum 
 2 parallel demon is running with 
max = 2* 1024 memory.

if you have more demon running and you keep on increase heap space. that also cause out of memory

Comment: Happens a lot in WSL when other processes take away memory, despite giving enough memory with JVM args

Answer (score 47):

**EDIT** Looks like there has been a few changes with the new versions of Gradle.

[Since 3.0 you *should* not disable the daemon on your CI anymore](https://docs.gradle.org/current/userguide/gradle_daemon.html#sec:disabling_the_daemon)

> [We] recommend using [the daemon] for both developers' machines and Continuous Integration servers.
>
> However, if you suspect that Daemon makes your CI builds unstable, you can disable it to use a fresh runtime for each build since the runtime is completely isolated from any previous builds.

**PREVIOUS ANSWER**

[It's recommended to turn off `daemon` on any CI server](https://docs.gradle.org/current/userguide/gradle_daemon.html#sec:stopping_an_existing_daemon). use this option to disable it

```
--no-daemon
```

Comment: I tried to build without daemon, but then I had a memory error. When I'm trying to increase a memory limit, I got a Daemon error again.

Is it possible that server where jenkins is running has a low memory?

Comment: And I built with `--no-daemon` and it's still giving `Gradle build daemon disappeared unexpectedly (it may have been killed or may have crashed)`.  Most peculiar.

Comment: I'm getting the same thing, added --no-daemon, and then checking the build logs, it explicitly says 'starting up daemon' nonsense.  Anyone know how to really kill it?

Comment: @SandroGedevanishvili I'm facing exactly the same as you, how did you solve the issue?

Comment: There was a problem with Memory on the machine I was building the project. After increasing memory to the machine, problem was solved.

Comment: This is a misquote or outdated ```Since Gradle 3.0, we enable Daemon by default and recommend using it for both developers' machines and Continuous Integration servers. However, if you suspect that Daemon makes your CI builds unstable, you can disable it to use a fresh runtime for each build since the runtime is completely isolated from any previous builds.```

Answer (score 33):

After getting this crash I tried several things to get the GradleDaemon to stop running on my CI server. None of which worked.

I found an answer on a gradle.org forum which suggested that the GradleDaemon would always run anyway. The --no-daemon flag would just make it run for this specific build rather than staying on indefinitely.

> If you specify JVM arguments that require forking, Gradle will fork a new JVM. Regardless of whether or not you want a daemon process, the class that runs is called GradleDaemon. The --no-daemon switch should cause the forked process to be single use instead of a long running daemon process, but it's still going to run the GradleDaemon class.

Source: https://discuss.gradle.org/t/no-daemon-switch-ineffective-if-jvm-settings-cause-new-fork/14919/5

I may be reading this wrong and I can't vouch for the validity of the answer, but I think the cause of this error is just a lack of memory for Gradle. As it is always going to run the GradleDaemon.

So I added

```
org.gradle.jvmargs=-Xmx1024m
```

to my `~/.gradle/gradle.properties` file and it no longer gave me that error.

Comment: Tried increasing the memory, but still receiving this error!

Comment: I'm up to `-Xmx4048m` and I still get the crash -.-

Answer (score 23):

It seems like it is a memory related issue. Nevertheless, disabling the daemon as suggested by Oleg does seem to help.

Use

> org.gradle.daemon=false

in

> gradle.properties

either in ~/.gradle folder or the project's folder.

Ref: https://docs.gradle.org/current/userguide/gradle_daemon.html#sec:disabling_the_daemon

Comment: I was having trouble launching sonarqube from my jenkins pipeline. With this option I managed to solve the problem.

Comment: Worked for my setup running gradle in a docker container from Jenkins

Answer (score 16):

In our case the issue was caused by the CI server passing environment variables with non-ascii characters (i.e. in the names of commit authors).

Adding `file.encoding=utf-8` to Gradle properties fixed the issue immediately.

Comment: This was exactly also my case but setting file.encoding=utf-8 doesn't help. I had to remove special characters directly on GitLab in my account settings.

Comment: I tried all above options but this one is working for me. Thanks

Comment: Here I have the "amazing" idea to use emojis on the prompt. With emojis, the gradle crashes. If you want to try by yourself, on Linux you can use ```export PS1=' \w '```. The error happens on Gradle 4.10.3, but was already fixed on Gradle 6.5 (the newest today).

Comment: Tried that, but no luck. Disabling the gradle daemon does the trick!

Answer (score 16):

It appears this type of problem (Gradle build daemon disappeared unexpectedly (it may have been killed or may have crashed)) is becoming more common as people move to GitHub workflows and GitHub Actions.

We never saw this problem when building locally (command line or Android Studio), or when building on our Jenkins build server. But as soon as we started testing builds through GitHub Workflows/Actions this type of build error would happen intermittently.

Every project is different, so it appears there are several solutions that may work. After a lot of experimenting with our builds, the only parameter that reliably fixed this problem was '***-XX:MaxMetaspaceSize***'.

```
GRADLE_OPTS: -Dorg.gradle.jvmargs="-XX:MaxMetaspaceSize=1g"
```

No changes to build.gradle, gradle.properties, gradle-wrapper.properties, etc. were needed in our case. Just the single GRADLE_OPTS line in our GitHub workflow yaml. This explanation from the [Java docs](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/17/gctuning/other-considerations.html) was the most helpful (avoiding unbounded growth of class metadata space).

> In previous releases of Java Hotspot VM, the class metadata was allocated in the so-called permanent generation. Starting with JDK 8, the permanent generation was removed and the class metadata is allocated in native memory. The amount of native memory that can be used for class metadata is by default unlimited. Use the option `-XX:MaxMetaspaceSize` to put an upper limit on the amount of native memory used for class metadata.

Source: https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/17/gctuning/other-considerations.html

Working example of GitHub Workflow:

```
jobs:
  build:

    runs-on: ubuntu-latest

    env:
      GRADLE_OPTS: -Dorg.gradle.jvmargs="-XX:MaxMetaspaceSize=1g"

    steps:
    - uses: actions/checkout@v2
      with:
        ref: 'master'
        fetch-depth: 0

    - name: Set up JDK 11
      uses: actions/setup-java@v2
      with:
        java-version: '11'
        distribution: 'temurin'
        cache: gradle

    - name: Gradle Build
      uses: gradle/gradle-build-action@v2
      with:
        arguments: build -x lint appDistributionUploadRelease
```

Comment: this solution doesn't work. now I get error: GC overhead limit exceeded. (java 8)

Comment: @naXastandswithUkraine the only thing this solution does is to configure your build to use a limited amount of memory for class metadata (1G in my example). This differs from the default of using unlimited memory for class metadata, which can easily cause an OOM condition and kill your build in non-obvious ways. Your problem appears to be something different (though you might try lowering the -XX:MaxMetaspaceSize parameter and see if that helps).

Comment: yes, sorry. my problem was caused by something else: too high `-Xmx -Xms` values

Comment: This resolved the trouble we were seeing. Using Git Hub Actions as mentioned. Thank you :)

Comment: export GRADLE_OPTS='-Dorg.gradle.jvmargs="-XX:MaxMetaspaceSize=1g"'

Answer (score 8):

```
gradle -Dorg.gradle.jvmargs=-Xmx1536m assembleDebug
```

Or add `org.gradle.jvmargs=-Xmx1536m` to **gradle.properties file**.

Comment: This solved the issue for me. The difference is that I've put more memory. To be specific, I'v used the "Sample, efficient gradle.properties" from this article: https://medium.com/@wasyl/make-your-gradle-builds-fast-again-ea323ce6a435

Answer (score 5):

No one else may run into this, as it's quite silly, but...

My issue was a **strange character being present in my commit message**...I had copied a previous commit message from gitlab which contained an emoji and pasted that into the title of a merge request, instead of the normal `:bug:` syntax.

akru's answer helped point me in the right direction

Comment: I have unicode characters in environment variables. The last message I see in the daemon log is:
`03:41:36.788 [DEBUG] [org.gradle.launcher.daemon.server.exec.EstablishBuildEnvironment] Configuring env variables: {PATH=/`

and then it vanishes.

Unfortunately for me, adding `file.encoding=utf-8` to `~/.gradle/gradle.properties` did not solve the issue

Answer (score 4):

`Gradle build daemon disappeared unexpectedly` in many cases mean gradle itself or even java crashed.
In my case it was `java`. Fill bugreport: https://bugzilla.redhat.com/show_bug.cgi?id=1408857

Look at files named like: `hs_err_pid%p.log` where %p is PID of process in directory from what you are run `gradle` task.

Update: It looks like [gradle itself issue](https://github.com/gradle/gradle/issues/778#issuecomment-283348494). In my case because of use native `jansi`. In issue provided workaround:

```
ln -sb /dev/null /home/pasha/.gradle/native/jansi/1.17.1/linux64/libjansi.so
```

Answer (score 3):

Wow, in my case closing the Android Studio and re-opening it worked just fine and the error was gone. :)

Answer (score 3):

In my case, removing `org.gradle.parallel=true` did the trick.

My `gradle.properties` for your reference:

```
org.gradle.daemon=false
org.gradle.jvmargs=-Xmx3g -XX:MaxMetaspaceSize=768m -XX:+HeapDumpOnOutOfMemoryError -Dfile.encoding=UTF-8
kotlin.compiler.execution.strategy=in-process
```

PS: I'm using this configuration for running Android Workflows with GitHub Actions (ubuntu-20.04)

Answer (score 1):

I have tried the `--no-daemon` solution but my build continued to fail with the same `DaemonDisappearedException`.

I solved this by increasing the RAM of the server I am running Jenkins upon. In AWS EC2 that meant having to increase the EC2 instance type which results to an increase RAM.

Answer (score 1):

Sometimes just doing Build -> Clean Project works - Give that a try before you start with the other gradle file changes.

Answer (score 1):

Most of the time you only need to restart Android Studio and it should work. Also you can do the following: File -> Sync Project with Gradle Files and then File -> Invalides Cachse / Restart.

Answer (score 1):

I was experiencing the same issue in GitHub Actions. As other answers mention, it seemed to be a memory issue.

The following settings worked nicely for me with the GitHub Ubuntu runner (no need to disable the deamon):

```
# ...
env:
  GRADLE_OPTS: -Dkotlin.incremental=false -Dorg.gradle.jvmargs="-Xmx4g -XX:MaxMetaspaceSize=2g -XX:+HeapDumpOnOutOfMemoryError -Dfile.encoding=UTF-8"
jobs:
  build:
    runs-on: ubuntu-latest
    steps:
      # ...
      - name: Build app
        run: ./gradlew assembleRelease --stacktrace
```

Answer (score 1):

I got the same error in Docker, and I tried to set org.gradle.daemon=false and all the above ways, but it didn't work . At last, I update the gradle to version 6.5 and the android gradle plugin to version 4.1.0. then the error disappeared.

Answer (score 1):

This is how it worked for me:

Enable the gradle deamon (this is the default with gradle 7).

> org.gradle.daemon=false

Install Jenkins Plugin: https://plugins.jenkins.io/gradle-daemon/

The Plugin will prevent to kill the deamon if another build is still using it.

Answer (score 0):

I was using Android Studio in Windows 7 and then this error appeared. What worked for me is killing Java.exe from Windows TaskManager.

Answer (score 0):

In my case, I was upgrading my android studio project and I use `ZelixKlassMaster` for obfuscating my code the issue wa that, I had my class-path on Zelix set to `27` but my project was using android `28` Hope this will help any future comers the way I debugged this was my `seed` file was printing out this error

```
ERROR: Invalid classpath in "classpath" statement at line 69 : "C:\Users\Rab\AppData\Local\Android\Sdk\platforms\android-27\android.jar" is not a valid path.
```

Answer (score 0):

I had the same issue, in the end there was a missing argument in the gradle file

Basically, this was a kotlin project, in which some experimental coroutine features were used. The class which used it was marked with

```
@OptIn(FlowPreview::class)
```

This requires adding the following argument in the build.gradle, although it was running just fine in android studio locally

```
kotlinOptions {
        jvmTarget = "1.8"
        freeCompilerArgs = [ "-Xopt-in=kotlin.RequiresOptIn"]
    }
```

Spent a lot of time looking for this one

Answer (score 0):

Before assemble task.

```
./gradlew --status
```

check daemon status.

Then

```
./gradlew --stop
```

to stop the daemon.

Use

```
./gradlew assemblerelease  --no-daemon -Dkotlin.compiler.execution.strategy="in-process"
```

to disable daemon.

Answer (score 0):

Add in `gradle.properties` file.

```
org.gradle.daemon=true <br>
org.gradle.jvmargs=-Xmx1024m <br>
android.useDeprecatedNdk=true <br>
android.useAndroidX=true <br>
android.enableJetifier=true <br>
file.encoding=utf-8
```

Answer (score 0):

i had the same issue  added these in the gradle.properties file

```
android.useAndroidX=true
android.enableJetifier=true
org.gradle.jvmargs = -Xmx2g
```

Answer (score 0):

In my case, I was using Docker for running the Gradle tasks from Github actions locally.

I had to increase docker memory, and it worked!

Answer (score 0):

It is a combination of number of parellel demons are running and how much heap space you are utlising.
so check how much heap is avaliable and create a configuration accordingly

```
-Xms256m -Xmx1024m
```

Number of forks = number of parallel test cases are exectuing

```
tasks.test { maxParallelForks=2 }
```

so ideally you can expect minimum 2 parallel demon is running with

> max = 2* 1024 memory.

**NOTE**: if you have more demon running and you keep on increase heap space. that also cause out of memory

So try to find an optimal count for **Fork** (number of parallel demons) 
and heap space for it

Answer (score 0):

Take my experience as an example, check and increase the swap space if needed, if you are running Linux OS.

It is recommended to have swap size as large as the ram size.

1. First, find the swap file, disable and delete it

   ```bash
   swapon --show
   NAME      TYPE SIZE USED PRIO
   /swapfile file   2G   0B   -2

   sudo swapoff /swapfile
   sudo rm  /swapfile
   ```
2. Create new swap space of size 16 GB (16 * 1024 = 16384). bs is the block size. Basically bs * count = bytes to be allocated (in this case 16 GB). Here bs = 1M (M stands for mega, so we are assigning 1MB block size) and we are allocating 16384 * 1MB (=16GB) to swap.

   ```bash
   sudo dd if=/dev/zero of=/swapfile bs=1M count=16384
   ```
3. Give it the read/write permission for root

   ```bash
   sudo chmod 600 /swapfile
   ```
4. Format it to swap

   ```bash
   sudo mkswap /swapfile
   ```
5. Turn on swap again

   ```bash
   sudo swapon /swapfile
   ```
6. Now reboot the PC for the above changes to take place.

Refer: https://askubuntu.com/a/1264577

Answer (score 0):

The problem still persists on different CIs. We running our routines on GitHub Actions on Linux build agents.

I decided to profile our build locally using **Visual VM**. I found out that each build spins up 2 daemons: 1 for gradle and 1 for kotlin compiler. Try limiting the memory for kotlin compiler. We are using this memory flags for gradle in gradle.properties:

```
# Dkotlin.daemon.jvm.options specifies memory limits for kotlin compiler
org.gradle.jvmargs=-Xmx4G -Dkotlin.daemon.jvm.options=-Xmx2G -XX:+HeapDumpOnOutOfMemoryError -XX:+UseParallelGC -Dfile.encoding=UTF-8
```

You must find a balance between gradle daemon heap and kotlin compiler daemon heap. gradle + kotlin < 7GB or else Linux will kill gradle daemon. It is important to leave some RAM for Linux or else it'll kill gradle daemon.

If you give not enough heap to gradle/kotlin daemons build will fail with OurOfMemoryError. Different technologies and projects may require different heap sizes for gradle and compiler. Unit tests/UI tests require additional kotlin daemon. Our project is relatively big and memory-hungry so we are only able to build artifacts with configs I showed above.

So in some cases default build agents may be insufficient for your project. In that case consider paying for stronger agents
or setup local build machine in your office to cover your needs.

Comment: Why 7gb ? This number seems a little bit arbitrary.

Comment: @alexandresachs cuz this is the RAM size of CI agent available to me. You need to check what RAM size has your CI agent.

Comment: ok yes thank you, that's what I was thinking :)

Answer (score 0):

In our case what fixed the error is updating **build-tools** version.

Target SDK in our case is 33 and we use build-tools for **Arxan SDK**.

There was a line on .yml file which uses build-tools v.29.0.0.

Updating that one to 33.0.2 fixed this issue.

In our case we use Github Actions which **runs-on: ubuntu-latest-8-cores**

And our gradle.properties jvmargs is:

```
org.gradle.jvmargs=-Xmx3g -Xms2g -Dfile.encoding=UTF-8 -XX:+CMSClassUnloadingEnabled -XX:MaxMetaspaceSize=1g -XX:+HeapDumpOnOutOfMemoryError
```

Answer (score 0):

I tried all solutions but no luck. I made a small change in my GitHub action workflow - stopped the gradle process and started again. After that, everything was good to go.

Am not getting the error of

> "Gradle build daemon disappeared unexpectedly (it may have been killed
> or may have crashed)"

My workflow code:

> ```
>   - name: Execute the flank command and run instrumentation tests.
>     run: |
>       ./gradlew --status
>       ./gradlew --stop
>       ./gradlew runFlank
> ```

Answer (score -2):

I had the same problem and after a long fight, I deleted some files and got some free space in memory.
then restarted android studio, now it works perfectly.

Answer (score -6):

Go to `/gradle.properties` then remove `org.gradle.jvmargs=-Xmx1024m` and if `org.gradle.jvmargs=-Xmx1024m` not available then Add this code in your `/gradle.properties`.

Comment: This answer is really unclear... remove it... then add it back?