# "Error:Failed to complete Gradle execution. Cause: Gradle build daemon disappeared unexpectedly (it may have been killed or may have crashed)"

Tags: android, gradle

my android studios started freezing up on me so I killed the task using task manager and when I reopened android studio I got this error:

> Error:Failed to complete Gradle execution. Cause: Gradle build daemon
>   disappeared unexpectedly (it may have been killed or may have crashed)

I tried cleaning and rebuilding the gradle and closing out and reopening android but it doesn't go away. The main answers on stack overflow seem to have outdated answers to click on things that are not there anymore such as `Settings-->Gradle-->GradleVM options`.

Comment: did you try searching for gradle in settings?

Comment: @creativecreatorormaybenot Yes I did I go under File > settings > Build, Execution, Deployment > Gradle and I see nothing that others say I am supposed to see unless this is not what they are refering to?

Comment: I have seen this happen when your machine is out of RAM ... assure you first kill off browsers etc ...

Answer (score 16):

i solved it from information issue tracker it happen in android 3.0 canary 4

1. go to gradle.properties
2. add this code
       `android.enableAapt2=false`

Comment: I am getting an error: `The option 'android.enableAapt2' is deprecated. The current default is 'true'. It has been removed from the current version of the Android Gradle plugin. This property has no effect, AAPT2 is now always used.`

Answer (score 6):

As outlined here:
https://developer.android.com/studio/intro/studio-config.html

To change the VM heap size do the following:
1. Help > Edit Custom VM Options
2. Add the line

> -XmxheapSize

, where heapSize is the size you want.
ie.

> -Xmx2g

for 2 gigs

Comment: its not relayed with heap size

Comment: Thanks Man! Working in new Android studio 3.0.

Answer (score 2):

It is because of due to lack of RAM memory in System.

1. Close all instance of Android Studio and restart it.
2. Make sure RAM has released some space:
   check in Windows Task Manager (by pressing <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Alt</kbd>+<kbd>Del</kbd> it will display)-->Performance.

Answer (score 2):

This error is mainly associated with Android Studio 3.0 Canary 3 AAPT2(Android Asset Packaging Tool).

> - Improved incremental resource processing with AAPT2. To enable AAPT2, add >the following to your `gradle.properties` file: `android.enableAapt2=true`.

this is a new feature added to android studio in order to increase its performance.

[Read more about improved android plugin.](https://developer.android.com/studio/preview/features/new-android-plugin.html)

But some how it cause an error Even a fresh install pop up this error on first start. You just need to do one thing to solve this issue.

1. Go to `gradle.properties`
2. Add this line `android.enableAapt2=false`(If its not already there.)

> If you set `android.enableAapt2=true` the same error will reappear.
>   **(`heapSize` have nothing to do with this issue.)**

Answer (score 1):

It may be happened cause of VM heap size. Once try by adding below line in 
**HELP --> Edit custom VM option**

```
-Xmx2g
```

where 2g is size of heap

Comment: I added this in **gradle.properties** like this

**org.gradle.jvmargs = -Xmx2g**.

Not created/edited any vm options and it's working. 
After this got another error, fixed by adding this **android.enableAapt2=false**

Answer (score 0):

Close your android studio and restart your computer.

Then try building it again. Sometimes this error goes out by simply restarting your computer.

Answer (score 0):

this error has to do with less ram so 
for me it was fixed after I closed the emulator
as emulator was consuming much ram and restarted it
android studio needs so much ram to run...
So free some memory and restart studio

Answer (score 0):

Im also having the same issue just close all other tabs and click invalid catches and restart the studio.It works fine