# Gradle build daemon disappeared unexpectedly... Android Studio 4.0.1

Tags: android, gradle

Whenever I run a project in Android Studio 4.0.1 I get the following error:

```
Gradle build daemon disappeared unexpectedly (it may have been killed or may have crashed)
```

I have tried:

- adding `org.gradle.jvmargs=-Xmx1024m`  to my ~/.gradle/gradle.properties file
- "Clear/Invalidate caches"
- adding `file.encoding=utf-8` to my ~/.gradle/gradle.properties file
- using `org.gradle.daemon=false` in my ~/.gradle/gradle.properties file
- deleting the .gradle file
- closing all instances of Android studio
- the solutions in [this post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41684610/errorfailed-to-complete-gradle-execution-cause-gradle-build-daemon-disappear)

and none have worked.

Does anyone have any idea why this is happening and how I can fix it?

Answer (score 0):

try with these solutions. one of them can solve your problem:

["Error:Failed to complete Gradle execution. Cause: Gradle build daemon disappeared unexpectedly (it may have been killed or may have crashed)"](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41684610/errorfailed-to-complete-gradle-execution-cause-gradle-build-daemon-disappear)