# Gitlab-CI Gradle build failed

Tags: android, docker, gradle, gitlab-ci, gitlab-ci-runner

When trying to build debug-apk for my project, it success for first commits but it keep failing after that giving this exception

```
Gradle build daemon disappeared unexpectedly (it may have been killed or may have crashed)
```

I've tried all solutions listed [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37171043/gradle-build-daemon-disappeared-unexpectedly-it-may-have-been-killed-or-may-hav)
I'm also tried to pull the image and run the process locally and it successes also it successes for fresh run on a diffrent server, so what is the issue here

my `.gitlab-ci.yml` file

```yml
image: thyrlian/android-sdk

before_script:
  - chmod +x ./gradlew

stages:
  - staging-build

staging:
  stage: staging-build
  script:
    - ./gradlew assembleDebug
  only:
    - staging
```

Comment: try upgrade to sdk 28

Comment: Done but still failing

Comment: Did you ever sort this?

Comment: Any update on this?