# Building docker image - Gradle build daemon disappeared unexpectedly

Tags: java, linux, docker, kotlin, gradle

SO family, I've been working on a project using Docker, Gradle, and Kotlin.The issue is
whenever I try to build a new docker image to deploy my latest changes, it gives an error

> **FAILURE: Build failed with an exception.**
> What went wrong:
> **Gradle build daemon disappeared unexpectedly (it may have been killed or may have crashed)**

I've tried to clear the memory multiple times by removing extra docker images and containers but couldn't succeed.
**The complete log file is attached.**

```
Step 1/19 : FROM xyz-image as build
 ---> 1ed71d09935d
Step 2/19 : RUN apk --no-cache --update add postgresql-client
 ---> Using cache
 ---> 8a7e3e5df31c
Step 3/19 : ENV APP_HOME=/workspace
 ---> Using cache
 ---> d46fa561ccbf
Step 4/19 : WORKDIR $APP_HOME
 ---> Using cache
 ---> 438c463befb9
Step 5/19 : COPY . .
 ---> 83e81d9f7ee7
Step 6/19 : RUN chmod 777 ./gradlew &&  ./gradlew clean build --stacktrace test jacocoTestReport sonarqube
 ---> Running in bc7a8bc75fed
./gradlew: line 1: Content#!/usr/bin/env: not found
Downloading https://services.gradle.org/distributions/gradle-5.4.1-bin.zip
...................................................................................

Welcome to Gradle 5.4.1!

Here are the highlights of this release:
 - Run builds with JDK12
 - New API for Incremental Tasks
 - Updates to native projects, including Swift 5 support

For more details see https://docs.gradle.org/5.4.1/release-notes.html

Starting a Gradle Daemon (subsequent builds will be faster)
> Task :clean UP-TO-DATE
> Task :compileKotlin

The message received from the daemon indicates that the daemon has disappeared.
Build request sent: Build{id=e70a3593-58dd-4d13-9cc0-3064a72c8175, currentDir=/workspace}
Attempting to read last messages from the daemon log...
Daemon pid: 49
  log file: /root/.gradle/daemon/5.4.1/daemon-49.out.log
----- Last  20 lines from daemon log file - daemon-49.out.log -----
05:57:15.389 [ERROR] [org.gradle.launcher.daemon.server.DaemonStateCoordinator] Command execution: started DaemonCommandExecution[command = Build{id=e70a3593-58dd-4d13-9cc0-3064a72c8175, currentDir=/workspace}, connection = DefaultDaemonConnection: socket connection from /127.0.0.1:34029 to /127.0.0.1:47592] after 0.0 minutes of idle
05:57:15.390 [INFO] [org.gradle.launcher.daemon.server.DaemonRegistryUpdater] Marking the daemon as busy, address: [b5d2ee0e-ade8-438a-a2a1-d0b724bd1ee9 port:34029, addresses:[/127.0.0.1]]
05:57:15.390 [DEBUG] [org.gradle.launcher.daemon.registry.PersistentDaemonRegistry] Marking busy by address: [b5d2ee0e-ade8-438a-a2a1-d0b724bd1ee9 port:34029, addresses:[/127.0.0.1]]
05:57:15.391 [DEBUG] [org.gradle.cache.internal.DefaultFileLockManager] Waiting to acquire exclusive lock on daemon addresses registry.
05:57:15.391 [DEBUG] [org.gradle.cache.internal.DefaultFileLockManager] Lock acquired on daemon addresses registry.
05:57:15.396 [DEBUG] [org.gradle.cache.internal.DefaultFileLockManager] Releasing lock on daemon addresses registry.
05:57:15.398 [DEBUG] [org.gradle.launcher.daemon.server.DaemonStateCoordinator] resetting idle timer
05:57:15.399 [DEBUG] [org.gradle.launcher.daemon.server.DaemonStateCoordinator] daemon is running. Sleeping until state changes.
05:57:15.400 [INFO] [org.gradle.launcher.daemon.server.exec.StartBuildOrRespondWithBusy] Daemon is about to start building Build{id=e70a3593-58dd-4d13-9cc0-3064a72c8175, currentDir=/workspace}. Dispatching build started information...
05:57:15.401 [DEBUG] [org.gradle.launcher.daemon.server.SynchronizedDispatchConnection] thread 17: dispatching class org.gradle.launcher.daemon.protocol.BuildStarted
05:57:15.403 [DEBUG] [org.gradle.launcher.daemon.server.exec.EstablishBuildEnvironment] Configuring env variables: {PATH=/usr/local/sbin:/usr/local/bin:/usr/sbin:/usr/bin:/sbin:/bin:/opt/jdk/bin, JAVA_JCE=standard, APP_HOME=/workspace, JAVA_HOME=/opt/jdk, OLDPWD=/workspace, GLIBC_VERSION=2.27-r0, LANG=C.UTF-8, JAVA_VERSION_MAJOR=8, HOSTNAME=bc7a8bc75fed, JAVA_VERSION_TOKEN=42970487e3af4f5aa5bca3f542482c60, GLIBC_REPO=https://github.com/sgerrand/alpine-pkg-glibc, JAVA_VERSION_MINOR=201, PWD=/workspace, JAVA_PACKAGE=jdk, JAVA_VERSION_BUILD=09, HOME=/root, SHLVL=2}
05:57:15.406 [DEBUG] [org.gradle.launcher.daemon.server.SynchronizedDispatchConnection] thread 15: received class org.gradle.launcher.daemon.protocol.CloseInput
05:57:15.407 [DEBUG] [org.gradle.launcher.daemon.server.DefaultDaemonConnection] thread 15: Received IO message from client: org.gradle.launcher.daemon.protocol.CloseInput@6181a140
05:57:15.411 [DEBUG] [org.gradle.launcher.daemon.server.exec.LogToClient] About to start relaying all logs to the client via the connection.
05:57:15.411 [INFO] [org.gradle.launcher.daemon.server.exec.LogToClient] The client will now receive all logging from the daemon (pid: 49). The daemon log file: /root/.gradle/daemon/5.4.1/daemon-49.out.log
05:57:15.414 [INFO] [org.gradle.launcher.daemon.server.exec.LogAndCheckHealth] Starting build in new daemon [memory: 477.6 MB]
05:57:15.415 [INFO] [org.gradle.launcher.daemon.server.exec.ForwardClientInput] Closing daemon's stdin at end of input.
05:57:15.416 [INFO] [org.gradle.launcher.daemon.server.exec.ForwardClientInput] The daemon will no longer process any standard input.
05:57:15.420 [DEBUG] [org.gradle.launcher.daemon.server.exec.ExecuteBuild] The daemon has started executing the build.
05:57:15.420 [DEBUG] [org.gradle.launcher.daemon.server.exec.ExecuteBuild] Executing build with daemon context: DefaultDaemonContext[uid=ff30b05d-4eb7-4a0f-b3e6-b9043b11d71f,javaHome=/opt/jdk1.8.0_201,daemonRegistryDir=/root/.gradle/daemon,pid=49,idleTimeout=10800000,priority=NORMAL,daemonOpts=-XX:MaxMetaspaceSize=256m,-XX:+HeapDumpOnOutOfMemoryError,-Xms256m,-Xmx512m,-Dfile.encoding=UTF-8,-Duser.country,-Duser.language=en,-Duser.variant]
----- End of the daemon log -----


FAILURE: Build failed with an exception.

* What went wrong:
Gradle build daemon disappeared unexpectedly (it may have been killed or may have crashed)

* Try:
Run with --info or --debug option to get more log output. Run with --scan to get full insights.

* Exception is:
org.gradle.launcher.daemon.client.DaemonDisappearedException: Gradle build daemon disappeared unexpectedly (it may have been killed or may have crashed)
        at org.gradle.launcher.daemon.client.DaemonClient.handleDaemonDisappearance(DaemonClient.java:241)
        at org.gradle.launcher.daemon.client.DaemonClient.monitorBuild(DaemonClient.java:217)
        at org.gradle.launcher.daemon.client.DaemonClient.executeBuild(DaemonClient.java:179)
        at org.gradle.launcher.daemon.client.DaemonClient.execute(DaemonClient.java:142)
        at org.gradle.launcher.daemon.client.DaemonClient.execute(DaemonClient.java:94)
        at org.gradle.launcher.cli.RunBuildAction.run(RunBuildAction.java:55)
        at org.gradle.internal.Actions$RunnableActionAdapter.execute(Actions.java:208)
        at org.gradle.launcher.cli.CommandLineActionFactory$ParseAndBuildAction.execute(CommandLineActionFactory.java:394)
        at org.gradle.launcher.cli.CommandLineActionFactory$ParseAndBuildAction.execute(CommandLineActionFactory.java:367)
        at org.gradle.launcher.cli.ExceptionReportingAction.execute(ExceptionReportingAction.java:37)
        at org.gradle.launcher.cli.ExceptionReportingAction.execute(ExceptionReportingAction.java:23)
        at org.gradle.launcher.cli.CommandLineActionFactory$WithLogging.execute(CommandLineActionFactory.java:360)
        at org.gradle.launcher.cli.CommandLineActionFactory$WithLogging.execute(CommandLineActionFactory.java:292)
        at org.gradle.launcher.Main.doAction(Main.java:36)
        at org.gradle.launcher.bootstrap.EntryPoint.run(EntryPoint.java:45)
        at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
        at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)
        at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
        at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:498)
        at org.gradle.launcher.bootstrap.ProcessBootstrap.runNoExit(ProcessBootstrap.java:60)
        at org.gradle.launcher.bootstrap.ProcessBootstrap.run(ProcessBootstrap.java:37)
        at org.gradle.launcher.GradleMain.main(GradleMain.java:23)
        at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
        at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)
        at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
        at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:498)
        at org.gradle.wrapper.BootstrapMainStarter.start(BootstrapMainStarter.java:31)
        at org.gradle.wrapper.WrapperExecutor.execute(WrapperExecutor.java:108)
        at org.gradle.wrapper.GradleWrapperMain.main(GradleWrapperMain.java:62)


* Get more help at https://help.gradle.org
The command '/bin/sh -c chmod 777 ./gradlew &&  ./gradlew clean build --stacktrace test jacocoTestReport sonarqube' returned a non-zero code: 1
```

***Thanks for your help in advance.***

Comment: Maybe the build was consuming too much RAM, so OS killed the process.

Comment: Thanks for the reply @kiner_shah. Is there any way I can identify what's the actual reason for this behaivor?

Comment: You can monitor the RAM used by the process during build using `top` command.

Comment: I've tried to increase gradle memory heap but did not work. I've checked the system Memory. it's only 1 GB available, do you think this can be the cause of the issue.

Comment: It's possible that since your RAM is just 1 GB and grade build consumes more than 1 GB, the OS kills the gradle build process.

Comment: @kiner_shah thanks for your kind help. I've one more question. can you please tell is it possible that we build docker image locally and then deploy it to our remote server?

Comment: Yes, you can create and build your own docker images. BTW have a look at this post: https://stackoverflow.com/q/37171043. It may be that the process isn't killed, but some other issue.

Answer (score 2):

I had a similar issue while I was trying to build a `ktor` application on `Digital Ocean` with `Docker`.

I added the following lines to my `gradle.properties` file

```
org.gradle.daemon=false
org.gradle.jvmargs=-Xmx1024m
```

and added Gradle `clean` into the `Dockerfile`

```
RUN ./gradlew clean
```