# Failed to exec spawn helper

Tags: java, docker, gradle, gradle-daemon

When running `docker-compose up` I get:

```
------
executor failed running [/bin/sh -c gradle shadowJar]: exit code: 1
ERROR: Service 'slack_bot' failed to build : Build failed
```

Then I tried running Gradle with `--info` and it mentions an exception in Gradle:

```
#11 4.123 An attempt to start the daemon took 0.107 secs.
#11 4.144 
#11 4.144 FAILURE: Build failed with an exception.
#11 4.145 
#11 4.145 * What went wrong:
#11 4.146 A problem occurred starting process 'Gradle build daemon'
```

Then I run it with `--stacktrace` to get the exception details:

```
#11 4.163 Starting a Gradle Daemon (subsequent builds will be faster)
#11 4.407 
#11 4.407 FAILURE: Build failed with an exception.
#11 4.407 
#11 4.408 * What went wrong:
#11 4.408 A problem occurred starting process 'Gradle build daemon'
#11 4.408 
#11 4.408 * Try:
#11 4.408 > Run with --info or --debug option to get more log output.
#11 4.408 > Run with --scan to get full insights.
#11 4.409 
#11 4.409 * Exception is:
#11 4.409 org.gradle.process.internal.ExecException: A problem occurred starting process 'Gradle build daemon'
#11 4.410       at org.gradle.process.internal.DefaultExecHandle.execExceptionFor(DefaultExecHandle.java:241)
#11 4.410       at org.gradle.process.internal.DefaultExecHandle.setEndStateInfo(DefaultExecHandle.java:218)
#11 4.410       at org.gradle.process.internal.DefaultExecHandle.failed(DefaultExecHandle.java:369)
#11 4.411       at org.gradle.process.internal.ExecHandleRunner.run(ExecHandleRunner.java:87)
#11 4.411       at org.gradle.internal.operations.CurrentBuildOperationPreservingRunnable.run(CurrentBuildOperationPreservingRunnable.java:38)
#11 4.411       at org.gradle.internal.concurrent.ExecutorPolicy$CatchAndRecordFailures.onExecute(ExecutorPolicy.java:64)
#11 4.411       at org.gradle.internal.concurrent.ManagedExecutorImpl$1.run(ManagedExecutorImpl.java:48)
#11 4.412       at java.base/java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1136)
#11 4.412       at java.base/java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:635)
#11 4.412       at java.base/java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:833)
#11 4.413 Caused by: net.rubygrapefruit.platform.NativeException: Could not start '/opt/java/openjdk/bin/java'
#11 4.413       at net.rubygrapefruit.platform.internal.DefaultProcessLauncher.start(DefaultProcessLauncher.java:27)
#11 4.413       at net.rubygrapefruit.platform.internal.WrapperProcessLauncher.start(WrapperProcessLauncher.java:36)
#11 4.415       at org.gradle.process.internal.ExecHandleRunner.startProcess(ExecHandleRunner.java:98)
#11 4.416       at org.gradle.process.internal.ExecHandleRunner.run(ExecHandleRunner.java:71)
#11 4.416       ... 6 more
#11 4.416 Caused by: java.io.IOException: Cannot run program "/opt/java/openjdk/bin/java" (in directory "/home/gradle/.gradle/daemon/7.4.2"): error=0, Failed to exec spawn helper: pid: 67, exit value: 1
#11 4.417       at java.base/java.lang.ProcessBuilder.start(ProcessBuilder.java:1143)
#11 4.417       at java.base/java.lang.ProcessBuilder.start(ProcessBuilder.java:1073)
#11 4.417       at net.rubygrapefruit.platform.internal.DefaultProcessLauncher.start(DefaultProcessLauncher.java:25)
#11 4.417       ... 9 more
#11 4.418 Caused by: java.io.IOException: error=0, Failed to exec spawn helper: pid: 67, exit value: 1
#11 4.418       at java.base/java.lang.ProcessImpl.forkAndExec(Native Method)
#11 4.418       at java.base/java.lang.ProcessImpl.<init>(ProcessImpl.java:314)
#11 4.418       at java.base/java.lang.ProcessImpl.start(ProcessImpl.java:244)
#11 4.418       at java.base/java.lang.ProcessBuilder.start(ProcessBuilder.java:1110)
#11 4.419       ... 11 more
#11 4.419 
#11 4.419 
#11 4.420 * Get more help at https://help.gradle.org
------
executor failed running [/bin/sh -c gradle shadowJar --stacktrace]: exit code: 1
ERROR: Service 'slack_bot' failed to build : Build failed
```

I don't know what else to try and the error details are not clear. Am I using the correct images?

`Dockerfile`:

```
FROM gradle:7.4.2-jdk17 as build
WORKDIR /usr/src/app
COPY . .
RUN gradle shadowJar

FROM adoptopenjdk:latest
WORKDIR /usr/src/app
COPY --from=build /usr/src/app/build/libs ./
```

`docker-compose.yml`:

```
version: "3.8"
services:
  slack_bot:
    container_name: slack_bot
    platform: linux/amd64
    build: .
    ports:
      - "8000:8000"
    environment:
      PORT: 8000
    command: java -jar build/libs/slack-bot-1.0-SNAPSHOT-all.jar
```

Using JDK11:

```
FROM gradle:7.4.2-jdk11 as build
WORKDIR /usr/src/app
COPY . .
RUN gradle shadowJar --info

FROM adoptopenjdk:latest
WORKDIR /usr/src/app
COPY --from=build /usr/src/app/build/libs ./
```

I get:

```
#11 27.96 Generating /home/gradle/.gradle/caches/7.4.2/generated-gradle-jars/gradle-api-7.4.2.jar
#11 27.96 ----- End of the daemon log -----
#11 27.96 
#11 27.96 JVM crash log found: file:///usr/src/app/hs_err_pid64.log
#11 28.00 
#11 28.00 FAILURE: Build failed with an exception.
#11 28.00 
#11 28.00 * What went wrong:
#11 28.00 Gradle build daemon disappeared unexpectedly (it may have been killed or may have crashed)
#11 28.00 
#11 28.00 * Try:
#11 28.00 > Run with --debug option to get more log output.
#11 28.01 > Run with --scan to get full insights.
#11 28.01 
#11 28.01 * Exception is:
#11 28.01 org.gradle.launcher.daemon.client.DaemonDisappearedException: Gradle build daemon disappeared unexpectedly (it may have been killed or may have crashed)
#11 28.01       at org.gradle.launcher.daemon.client.DaemonClient.handleDaemonDisappearance(DaemonClient.java:269)
#11 28.01       at org.gradle.launcher.daemon.client.DaemonClient.monitorBuild(DaemonClient.java:242)
#11 28.01       at org.gradle.launcher.daemon.client.DaemonClient.executeBuild(DaemonClient.java:204)
#11 28.01       at org.gradle.launcher.daemon.client.DaemonClient.execute(DaemonClient.java:167)
#11 28.01       at org.gradle.launcher.daemon.client.DaemonClient.execute(DaemonClient.java:99)
#11 28.01       at org.gradle.launcher.cli.RunBuildAction.run(RunBuildAction.java:57)
#11 28.01       at org.gradle.internal.Actions$RunnableActionAdapter.execute(Actions.java:210)
#11 28.01       at org.gradle.launcher.cli.DefaultCommandLineActionFactory$ParseAndBuildAction.execute(DefaultCommandLineActionFactory.java:275)
#11 28.01       at org.gradle.launcher.cli.DefaultCommandLineActionFactory$ParseAndBuildAction.execute(DefaultCommandLineActionFactory.java:247)
#11 28.01       at org.gradle.launcher.cli.DebugLoggerWarningAction.execute(DebugLoggerWarningAction.java:82)
#11 28.01       at org.gradle.launcher.cli.DebugLoggerWarningAction.execute(DebugLoggerWarningAction.java:30)
#11 28.01       at org.gradle.launcher.cli.WelcomeMessageAction.execute(WelcomeMessageAction.java:92)
#11 28.01       at org.gradle.launcher.cli.WelcomeMessageAction.execute(WelcomeMessageAction.java:38)
#11 28.01       at org.gradle.launcher.cli.NativeServicesInitializingAction.execute(NativeServicesInitializingAction.java:44)
#11 28.01       at org.gradle.launcher.cli.NativeServicesInitializingAction.execute(NativeServicesInitializingAction.java:26)
#11 28.01       at org.gradle.launcher.cli.ExceptionReportingAction.execute(ExceptionReportingAction.java:41)
#11 28.01       at org.gradle.launcher.cli.ExceptionReportingAction.execute(ExceptionReportingAction.java:26)
#11 28.01       at org.gradle.launcher.cli.DefaultCommandLineActionFactory$WithLogging.execute(DefaultCommandLineActionFactory.java:240)
#11 28.01       at org.gradle.launcher.Main.doAction(Main.java:35)
#11 28.01       at org.gradle.launcher.bootstrap.EntryPoint.run(EntryPoint.java:50)
#11 28.01       at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
#11 28.01       at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)
#11 28.01       at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
#11 28.01       at java.base/java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:566)
#11 28.01       at org.gradle.launcher.bootstrap.ProcessBootstrap.runNoExit(ProcessBootstrap.java:60)
#11 28.01       at org.gradle.launcher.bootstrap.ProcessBootstrap.run(ProcessBootstrap.java:37)
#11 28.01       at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
#11 28.01       at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)
#11 28.01       at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
#11 28.01       at java.base/java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:566)
#11 28.01       at org.gradle.launcher.GradleMain.main(GradleMain.java:34)
#11 28.01 
#11 28.01 
#11 28.01 * Get more help at https://help.gradle.org
------
executor failed running [/bin/sh -c gradle shadowJar --info --stacktrace]: exit code: 1
ERROR: Service 'slack_bot' failed to build : Build failed
```

Comment: Use a compatible version, alike JDK 11 - or a later Gradle version.

Comment: Gradle 7.4.2 and JDK18 are the latest but I'll try an older JDK

Comment: Please read slowly, I've wrote "compatible" and not "latest"... a Gradle version with JDK 18 compatibility had only recently been announced. For Android Java it's even required to use JDK 11.

Comment: right. I downgraded to JDK17 based on your tip (checked that Gradle >= 7.3 supports JDK17: https://docs.gradle.org/current/userguide/compatibility.html)
then I updated the question with the output

Answer (score 7):

The error is resolved by adding the below flag to File | Settings | Build, Execution, Deployment | Compiler | * build process VM options text field in Intellij

```
-Djdk.lang.Process.launchMechanism=vfork
```

Reference:

https://youtrack.jetbrains.com/issue/IDEA-304440/Cannot-run-program-java-failed-to-exec-spawn-helper-exit-value-1#focus=Comments-27-6736675.0-0

Comment: It worked for me. Specs: JetBrains Gateway 2023.1, client version 2023.1.3 RC, Windows 11 PRO + WSL2

Answer (score 2):

It doesn't fail to build - it already fails the start the Gradle daemon ...
This is the `jspawnhelper` at fault; it possibly might lack `x` permission:

```
RUN chmod +x $JAVA_HOME/lib/jspawnhelper
RUN gradle :shadowJar
```

- Or disable the Gradle daemon altogether; with one-shot builds it doesn't make a difference.
- Or try `-Djdk.lang.Process.launchMechanism=vfork`?

Comment: tried all those tips and combinations but always get the same outcome.. :/

Comment: Try Gradle 7.4.2 with JDK 11, as I've said... this is at least a combination known to be compatible; or use a Java container and the Gradle wrapper, eg: https://github.com/syslogic/cloudbuild-android

Comment: ok then I get a different exception - I've updated the question

Comment: See https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37171043 ...maybe there's just too little RAM?

Answer (score 1):

Gradle 7.4.2 is broken. You should downgrade to 7.4.1

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).

Answer (score 1):

The JAVA_HOME system variable on the server running the IDE backend needs to be of version jdk11+, or as @Sai Srikar Mutya mentioned, add "-Djdk.lang.Process.launchMechanism=vfork" after "build process VM options" (I tried adding this parameter and it would compile the project particularly slowly).